# How to invoke custom query in Spring Boot JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to invoke a custom query through a custom method in Spring Boot Data JPA.

```
    @Repository
    public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Integer> {
    
    
        @Query("select * from flight")
        void executeMyQuery();
    }
```

But when try to run the application, I am getting below error

```
No property 'executeMyQuery' found for type 'Flight'
```

I am using Spring Boot Version 3.1.1 (*tried with 2.7.13 as well but no luck*)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you run it? Please add the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use JPQL inside `@Query` annotation for custom query and also you can use return type to get the results.

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Flight f")
List<Flight> fetchFlights();
```

Here is more details https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Or you can use native SQL for query using `nativeQuery = true`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Flight", nativeQuery = true)
List<Flight> fetchFlights();
```

BTW you can also use existing `findAll()` method also to fetch all data.

```
flightRepository.findAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have been trying this for hours but this same thing was not working as i was doing a wrong import through out for the @Query annotation. I was importing `import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;` instead of `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;`

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a query in the repo with annotation @Query like this

```
@Query("from student where address=?1 and name=?2")
List<Student> findByAddressSorted(String address,String name);
```